# Multiple database migration in one go

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nuget, entity-framework-migrations

I have four different databases in my code first project which need migrations. Consider the following :

```
-- Enabling migrations
Enable-Migrations -StartUpProjectName SampleProject -MigrationsDirectory Migrations\DB1Configuration -ContextTypeName DB1ConfigurationDbContext -ContextAssemblyName SampleProject -ConnectionStringName MyDbContext1

Enable-Migrations -StartUpProjectName SampleProject -MigrationsDirectory Migrations\DB2Configuration -ContextTypeName DB2ConfigurationDbContext -ContextAssemblyName SampleProject -ConnectionStringName MyDbContext2

Enable-Migrations -StartUpProjectName SampleProject -MigrationsDirectory Migrations\DB3Configuration -ContextTypeName DB3ConfigurationDbContext -ContextAssemblyName SampleProject -ConnectionStringName MyDbContext3

Enable-Migrations -StartUpProjectName SampleProject -MigrationsDirectory Migrations\DB4Configuration -ContextTypeName DB4ConfigurationDbContext -ContextAssemblyName SampleProject -ConnectionStringName MyDbContext4

-- Addning migrations

Add-Migration -StartUpProjectName SampleProject -Name InitialCreate -ConfigurationTypeName SampleProject.Migrations.DB2Configuration.Configuration -ConnectionStringName MyDbContext1

Add-Migration -StartUpProjectName SampleProject -Name InitialCreate -ConfigurationTypeName SampleProject.Migrations.DB1Configuration.Configuration -ConnectionStringName MyDbContext2

Add-Migration -StartUpProjectName SampleProject -Name InitialCreate -ConfigurationTypeName SampleProject.Migrations.DB3Configuration.Configuration -ConnectionStringName MyDbContext3

Add-Migration -StartUpProjectName SampleProject -Name InitialCreate -ConfigurationTypeName SampleProject.Migrations.DB4Configuration.Configuration -ConnectionStringName MyDbContext4

--Create the database

Update-Database -StartUpProjectName SampleProject -ConfigurationTypeName SampleProject.Migrations.DB2Configuration.Configuration -ConnectionStringName MyDbContext1

Update-Database -StartUpProjectName SampleProject -ConfigurationTypeName SampleProject.Migrations.DB1Configuration.Configuration -ConnectionStringName MyDbContext2

Update-Database -StartUpProjectName SampleProject -ConfigurationTypeName SampleProject.Migrations.DB3Configuration.Configuration -ConnectionStringName MyDbContext3

Update-Database -StartUpProjectName SampleProject -ConfigurationTypeName SampleProject.Migrations.DB4Configuration.Configuration -ConnectionStringName MyDbContext4
```

Right now I need to run every single one of the above in Package Manager console to perform the migration however Ideally I would like to be able to put above in something like a script and run a single command to perform above operation. Is this possible (migrating multiple databases in one go)? Could you please provide the sample?

Comment: Readers: I found this article by Julie Lerman helpful. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn948104.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can use a power shell script for that.
Just copy all your commands to text file, assign and use arguments,set extension to ps1 and save to solution root folder.
Example **UpdateAllDatabases.ps1**:

```
$migrationName = $args[0]
Enable-Migrations -StartUpProjectName SampleProject -MigrationsDirectory Migrations\DB1Configuration -ContextTypeName DB1ConfigurationDbContext -ContextAssemblyName SampleProject -ConnectionStringName MyDbContext1
...
Add-Migration -StartUpProjectName SampleProject -Name $migrationName -ConfigurationTypeName SampleProject.Migrations.DB2Configuration.Configuration -ConnectionStringName MyDbContext1
...
Update-Database -StartUpProjectName SampleProject -ConfigurationTypeName SampleProject.Migrations.DB1Configuration.Configuration -ConnectionStringName MyDbContext1
```

Now you can execute script from Package Manager Console by just calling

> .\UpdateAllDatabases.ps1 InitialCreate

Answer (score 1):

First Go to Enable-Migration for your Project, After that

```
Add-Migration -ConfigurationTypeName Sample_Project.Migrations.ApplicationDbContext.Configuration "InitialDatabaseCreation"


Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName Sample_Project.Migrations.Project_SystemContext.Configuration
```

Change Dbcontext name as your project ,Same Code used for Multiple Migrations...